# What is equivalent HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

Previously, to track screen view in Google Analytics, I'm using the following code snippet. It is very convenient, as I need not to pass `Activity` and `Context` around. To use it, I just need to call `Utils.trackGAView("ShareDialogFragment");` any where in the code.

### Google Analytics

```
public static Tracker getTracker() {
    if (false == isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
        return null;
    }

    if (tracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(JStockApplication.instance());
        tracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.app_tracker);
    }
    return tracker;
}

public static void trackGAView(String view) {
    Tracker tracker = Utils.getTracker();
    if (tracker == null) {
        return;
    }
    tracker.setScreenName(view);
    tracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}
```

However, in Firebase, it is not really that convinient, as it requires an `Activity` - https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews

Not every place in the code we have access to the `Activity` object.

### Firebase

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(activity, screenName, null /* class override */);
```

Is there any good technique, which I can keep track screen view in Firebase, without the need of passing around `Activity`?